# eclipse with flex plugin for red5

Tags: java, eclipse, flash, apache-flex, red5

I've just started to mess around with red5 , I can't say it was easy to get it run at the first place, but after a day on google I finally succeed.

The first thing I had to face is the poor documentation of this server. I couldn't find any good tutorials about making apps (I would pay for a good one, but still nothing) for it, but it doesn't matter since it's free.

I found this : [Adobe TV](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/360flex-conference/building-red5-applications-by-chris-allen/) . It's the best starting point I could find so far. The only thing is that I can't set up the same working enviroment as the guy has in the video. I understand it is eclipse (i have that) , and i know he is using flex plugin, but how do I get eclipse to debug mxml files as he does? (around 3.20 in the video) . I downloaded the [flex plugin](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flex_eclipse), but after I install it, eclipse stays exactly the same as before.

PLease note I am new to eclipse (and JAVA and flash -huhh... :D - ).

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you install Flash Builder as a plugin to your eclipse instance?  Have you created a Flash Builder project?  Generally to get Flash Builder to debug MXML files, just add a breakpoint and launch your main application file in "Debug" mode.  There is a special button for debugging an app (right next to the one for profiling and app and the one for running an app not in debug mode).

Comment: "Did you install Flash Builder as a plugin to your eclipse instance?" What do you mean with this? I downloaded an exe, so it installed "itself". I did exactly what the guy did on the video. I started a dynamic web project.

Comment: Flash Builder is available in two "forms"... one as a stand alone version--which is just Eclipse and Flash Builder bundled together--and the other as an Eclipse plugin.  If you already had a version of Eclipse installed; you'll need to install Flash Builder as a plugin to that Eclipse install in order to make use of Flash Builder features from projects in that eclipse.  Dynamic Web Project is not one of the Flex project types available from Flash Builder; so that is probably why you can't debug MXML from that project.

Comment: I know that, but as you see on my second link, it's pointing to a site where you can download the plugin as an exe. When you install the FlexPlugin it asks for your Eclipse directory so it can expand it. It also gives you a shortcut so you can start eclipse with this plugin. If you watch the video from around 3:00, he starts a dynamic web project and still can debug MXML.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more IDE called FDT for flex app development. They are using eclipse. Worthy to try this IDE http://fdt.powerflasher.com/ this is available linux too. This is does not support red5 by native. But you can just simply create as java project.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere the Flex Development to do with flashdevelop: http://www.flashdevelop.org/

it is a very nice openen source code editor. Configuration is really easy and takes just 1 Minute. The only thing to do is to configure the path of the flex sdk. Debugging is nice and i love the code completition feature.